# Reading from a csv file and separating key and value and returning a map in java

Tags: java, string, csv, split

i'm reading from a csv file that has a column that contains a key value pair in one of the columns.  A sample from the csv file:

```
Country    Product    Baseurl              ParamAndMacro
USA        Oil        http://usa.com      key={value}&key2={value2}&key3={value3}
```

I'm attempting to split the column called **ParamAndMacro** and store it in a hashMap by key value pair. 
My first attempt, i was successful at splitting the string using the split function:

```
public Map<String, String> splitString(String s) {
    // String s represents ParamAndMacro
    String[] split = s.split("=|\\&");
    int length = split.length;
    Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i=0; i<length; i+=2){
          maps.put(split[i], split[i+1]);
     } 
    return maps;
}
```

This works but it doesn't check for corner cases. Such as `"key={value}&key2={value2}&key3="` or `"key={value}&key2={value2}&key3=&"` as this will throw an exception. Basically if a value is empty store an object with the key and an empty value. **Ex: `{key3=}`. Also if a key is missing do not store it in the map, i.e use a logger to report the error, skip it and continue**. So far i have attempted it one pass but i fail to check if a key is missing. Below is my implementation and how is my algorithm and if it's efficient.

So i implemented a split function below:

```
public Map<String, String> splitString(String s){
 Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<>();
 int length = s.length();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 String key = "";
 String value = "";

char prev = ' ';
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    char a = s.charAt(i);
    if ( a != '=' && a != '&' && prev != a) {
           sb.append(a);        
      }

    else if( a == '=' && prev != a && prev != '&') {
          key = sb.toString();
          sb = new StringBuilder();
      }

    else if (a=='&' && prev != a && prev != '=') {
          value = sb.toString();
          sb = new StringBuilder();
          maps.put(key, value);
            }
    else if (prev=='=' && a == '&') {
          value = "";
          maps.put(key, value);
          sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
            prev = a;
    }
    return maps;
}
```

**NOTE: ** I am reading from a csv file. The parameters and macros could be long and also wanted to know if my algorithm is efficient in a one pass.

**Expected outputs**

`key={value}&key2={value2}&key3=&` is:

**Output:** `{key={value}, key2={value2}, key3=}`

`key={value}&key2={value2}&key3=` is:

**Output:** `{key={value}, key2={value2}, key3=}`

`key={value}&{value2}&key3=` is:

**Output:** `{key={value}, key3="}`

`={value}&key2={value2}&key3=` is:

**Output:** `{key2={value2}, key3=}`

Comment: `key={value}&key2={value2}` is NOT a CSV format. Where is COMMA ?

Comment: what is the expected outputs?

Comment: @JacekCz updated the question. Sorry forgot to include the details of the csv file. I was able to read the contents of the file but i have to split the **ParamAndMacro** to generate a url with params.

Comment: @YCF_L displayed the output

Comment: i will try and let you know i'm a little tired now :)

Comment: @YCF_L thanks man appreciate it